Yocto: failed to add Qt6Linguist
I tried to include Qt6Linguist to my qt application through Yocto.
Thus, I added in my CMakeLists.txt the following lines :
find_package(Qt6 6.4 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Quick Network VirtualKeyboard Concurrent LinguistTools)

and
target_link_libraries(app${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE
    Qt6::Quick
    Qt6::VirtualKeyboard
    Qt6::Concurrent
    Qt6::LinguistTools
)

This is my recipe:
SUMMARY = "Recipe for myqtapp"
DESCRIPTION = "Provide qt executable of myapp"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend := "${THISDIR}:"

inherit populate_sdk_qt6_base qt6-cmake qt6-paths

DEPENDS += "qtdeclarative-native qtvirtualkeyboard"
DEPENDS += "qttools"
SRC_URI = "git://git@github.com/myapp/myapp-QT.git;protocol=ssh;branch=develop;name=myapp;destsuffix=myapp"

#SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"
SRCREV = "e0b57555d453f4469e0c76da4770eb4657cbcac3"

S = "${WORKDIR}/myappQt"

EXECUTABLE = "myappQt"
EXTRA_OECMAKE += " -DQT_DEBUG_FIND_PACKAGE=ON"

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}/${bindir}
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/build/app${EXECUTABLE} ${D}/${bindir}/app${EXECUTABLE}
    ln -rs ${D}/${bindir}/app${EXECUTABLE} ${D}/${bindir}/b2qt
}

FILES_${PN} += " ${bindir}/app${EXECUTABLE} "
FILES_${PN} += " ${bindir}/b2qt "

However during do_configure step, there is a failure :
 -- Could NOT find Qt6LinguistTools (missing: Qt6LinguistTools_DIR)
| CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package):
|   Found package configuration file:
| 
|     /home/user/work/chat/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/myappqt/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/cmake/Qt6/Qt6Config.cmake
| 
|   but it set Qt6_FOUND to FALSE so package "Qt6" is considered to be NOT
|   FOUND.  Reason given by package:
| 
|   Failed to find required Qt component "LinguistTools".
| 
|   Expected Config file at
|   "/home/user/work/chat/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/myappqt/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/cmake/Qt6LinguistTools/Qt6LinguistToolsConfig.cmake"
|   does NOT exist
| 
| 
| 
|   Configuring with --debug-find-pkg=Qt6LinguistTools might reveal details why
|   the package was not found.
| 
|    find_package search path values and other context for the last package that was not found:
|     CMAKE_MODULE_PATH: /home/user/work/chat/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/myappqt/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/cmake/Modules/;/home/user/work/chat/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/myappqt/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/cmake/Modules/;/home/user/work/chat/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/myappqt/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/cmake/Qt6;/home/user/work/chat/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/myappqt/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/cmake/Qt6/3rdparty/extra-cmake-modules/find-modules;/home/user/work/chat/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/myappqt/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/cmake/Qt6/3rdparty/kwin
|     CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/user/work/chat/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/myappqt/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/cmake
|     $ENV{CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}:
|     CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH: /home/user/work/chat/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/myappqt/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr;/home/user/work/chat/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/myappqt/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot;/home/user/work/chat/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/myappqt/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native;/home/user/work/chat/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/myappqt/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/perl-native;/home/user/work/chat/build/tmp/hosttools
|     _qt_additional_packages_prefix_paths:
|     _qt_additional_host_packages_prefix_paths:
|     _qt_cmake_dir: /home/user/work/chat/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/myappqt/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/cmake
|     QT_HOST_PATH: /home/user/work/chat/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/myappqt/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr
|     Qt6HostInfo_DIR: /home/user/work/chat/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/myappqt/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/cmake/Qt6HostInfo
|     Qt6_DIR: /home/user/work/chat/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/myappqt/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/cmake/Qt6
|     CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE: /home/user/work/chat/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/myappqt/1.0-r0/toolchain.cmake
|     CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE: ONLY
|     CMAKE_SYSROOT:
|     $ENV{PATH}: /home/user/work/chat/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/usr/bin:/home/user/work/chat/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/myappqt/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/python3-native:/home/user/work/chat/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/myappqt/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/perl-native:/home/user/work/chat/sources/poky/scripts:/home/user/work/chat/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/myappqt/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi:/home/user/work/chat/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/myappqt/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/crossscripts:/home/user/work/chat/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/myappqt/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/sbin:/home/user/work/chat/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/myappqt/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin:/home/user/work/chat/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/myappqt/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/sbin:/home/user/work/chat/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/myappqt/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/bin:/home/user/work/chat/sources/poky/bitbake/bin:/home/user/work/chat/build/tmp/hosttools


Where did you find the documentation for adding "Qt6::Linguist" as a component?

Also the only reason I bring this up is because I found this Qt documentation saying that QTLinguist is defined as LinguistTools in CMake.

I updated the question with more logs, and the fix you suggested @Willyrains

Can you also post your local.conf?

There is nothing related to Qt in my local.conf. It will not help

Do you not need to add qtlinguist to your Yocto recipe DEPENDS?

I see it mentioned elsewhere as qttools-native too

No i just added qttools and qttools-native then it worked somehow
